# $x^n\{x^n\}<\frac{1}{4}$ for all $n\geq2016$ implies $x$ is an integer

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

> A real number $x>1$ has the property that $x^n\{x^n\}<\frac{1}{4}$ for all $n\geq 2016$, where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$. Prove that $x$ is an integer.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this question. We can set $x=q+r$, where $q\in\mathbb{N},0\leq r<1$, so $\{x\}=r$. However, analyzing terms of the expansion seems difficult, and I can't think of a better way.

Also, how important is the constant $2016$? Some empirical evidence suggests that smaller $n$ lead to $x^n\{x^n\}$ being smaller?

Comment: I agree that $2016$ is relatively arbitrary and the only reason they choose that exact number that this is the year $2016$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $k$ large enough that $x^k \gt 100$ and $k \ge 2016$.  Write $x^k=q+r, q \in \Bbb N$, so we know $0\le r \lt \frac 1{400}$.  $x^{2k}=q^2+2qr+r^2$.  As $qr \lt \frac 14$, $\{x^{2k}\}=2qr+r^2 \lt \frac 12+\frac 1{160000}, x^{2k}\{x^{2k}\} \gt 2q^3r$ so we have multplied the product by $2q^2 \gt 20000$.  If $r \gt 0$, we can continue squaring until we find a $k'$ such that $x^{k'}\{x^{k'}\} \gt \frac 14$

Comment: How do we know that $r<\frac{1}{400}$? Also, how does this imply $qr<\frac{1}{4}$, if $q>100$?

Comment: @jlammy:  we know $r \lt \frac 1{400}$ because $x^k \gt 100$ and $x^kr \lt \frac 14$.  Then since $x^k \ge q, x^kr \lt \frac 14 \implies qr \lt \frac 14$

Comment: The point is the fractional part of $x^{2k}$ is larger than the fractional part of $x^k$.  To prove that we have to prove it doesn't carry.